# Why does the invocation show "n/a"?

Tags: jprofiler

I use maven to run my web application, then I use the JProfiler to trace it.
But the invocation shows n/a, what do I miss any settings ?

This is what I start server's command.

```
maven tomcat7:run
```

[image: JProfiler Hot Spots view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use sampling as the method call recording type, the profiler has no way of knowing how many invocations there were for any method. With instrumentation, the entry and exit of method invocations are tracked and an invocation count can be shown. You can switch between sampling and instrumentation in the session startup dialog by editing the call tree recording setting.

For an in-depth explanation, see the [help topic on method call recording](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/main/methodCallRecording.html).

Comment: Thanks , I use the Instrumentation type, the invocations can be shown.